selenium chrome driver not working on IIS
I am facing a problem that selenium chrome driver not opening from web application when deployed on IIS, although it is working fine locally.
I want single signon application using that, login another application passing userId and password and application link

What you mean not opening? Did it throw any error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
